# Parameter ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, arguments, actionlistener

I can't pass those three arguments `allField, nbGrpGen, Na`  in my actionListener.
Even if there are global, Eclipse tell me that they "cannot be resolved to a variable".
If those elements are declared in the class `Panneau_fenetre1A`, it works. But I can't do that because, I need the value of Na.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Panneau_fenetre1A extends JPanel {

    JLabel phrase = new JLabel(
            "Veuillez indiquer le nombre de groupe generalisant par Niveau");
    JButton boutonOK = new JButton("OK");

    public Panneau_fenetre1A(int Na) {
        final JTextField[] allField = new JTextField[Na];
        final String[] nbGrpGen = new String[Na];
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            allField[i] = new JTextField(String.valueOf(0));
            allField[i].setBounds(150, 350 + i * 25, 20, 20);
            add(allField[i]);
        }
        boutonOK.addActionListener(new ecout5());
    }

    class ecout5 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                nbGrpGen[i] = allField[i].getText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow java classes naming convention ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple alternatives to accomplish this.
1) Dispose of ecout5 and use an Anonymous ActionListener, this is less verbose, and easier understandable for someone used to java:

```
boutonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        for(int i = 0;i < Na ;i++)
        {
            nbGrpGen[i] = allField[i].getText();
        }                   
    }
}
```

More about anonymous classes in Java here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm (Cannot find a quote that captures the essence easily, if this goes stale, just google "Java anonymous classes")

2) Pass Na as a parameter into ecout5's constructor, this may be cleaner and easier to read and reuse:

```
boutonOK.addActionListener(new ecout5(Na));

...

class ecout5 implements ActionListener 
{   
    private int Na;
    public ecout5(int Na)
    {
        this.Na = Na;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        for(int i = 0;i < Na ;i++)
        {
            nbGrpGen[i] = allField[i].getText();
        }                   
    }
```

There are probably more options as well, but I hope one of the mentioned should do

Comment: (Personally) I don't know an `Anonymous` is always the best choice (obviously in this context I would agree with you), the problem is when the class begins to blow out to tens of lines and then you have developers who insist on using it for every button they have, it makes the code unreadable and reduces the re-usability (again in this context it would probably fit well).  When making the choice to use an Anonymous class, think about the overall design first ;) IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer agreed! Anonymous classes should be used strictly when they are so easy to understand that it would be a waste of space and time to make up a name and full class definition for it. As I make a (maybe failed) attempt to point out, they could provide or destroy readability, depending on the situation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `na` a global variable:

```
private int na;

public Panneau_fenetre1A(int na)
{
    this.na = na;
    // la reste ici
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.lang.Integer;

class Panneau_fenetre1A extends JPanel
{

  JLabel phrase = new JLabel("Veuillez indiquer le nombre de groupe generalisant par Niveau");
  JButton boutonOK = new JButton ("OK");


  public Panneau_fenetre1A(final int Na)
  {
    final JTextField[] allField = new JTextField [Na];
    final String[] nbGrpGen = new String [Na];
    for(int i = 0;i < Na;i++)
    {
      allField[i] = new JTextField(String.valueOf(0));
      allField[i].setBounds(150, 350 + i * 25, 20, 20);
      add(allField[i]);
    }

    boutonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
      {

        for(int i = 0;i < Na ;i++)
        {
          nbGrpGen[i] = allField[i].getText();

        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to make the `Na` parameter final too: `public Panneau_fenetre1A(final int Na)`